# PHP / HTML File Upload Not Recognizing Screenshot Images

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload

I am building a file upload tool for my website and am running into a strange issue. The html input is set up to accept `image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, .pdf` files and it works fine when I am using it to upload PDFs or images that came from a camera or a design software.

However, when I upload an image (png) that was a screenshot taken on my Mac, the $_FILES has a value for the `name` attribute, but has no values for the `tmp_name, type, error, size` attributes. I've tried renaming the file to see if that was the issue, and that doesn't appear to be the problem either.

This is the output I get when I run `print_r($_FILES)`:

```
Array ( [fileupload] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Screen Shot 2020-12-23 at 2.10.06 PM.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) )

Warning: mime_content_type(): Empty filename or path in pro_testupload.php on line 87
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in pro_testupload.php on line 91
Warning: mime_content_type(): Empty filename or path in pro_testupload.php on line 103
```

Does anyone have any idea about what is going on here? Below is my code:

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="POST" action="_process/pro_testupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload[]" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, .pdf" multiple required>
    <button class="btn waves-effect black waves-light" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  FILE FORMAT CHECKING FUNCTIONS
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  function check_image($filename) {
    // Check mime type using PHPs own built in functions (as client side mime type is vulnerable to exploitation)
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($filename);
    $allowed_file_types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'];

    // Check the file is actually an image
    $check = getimagesize($filename);

    // Perform all checks
    if (in_array($mime_type, $allowed_file_types) && is_array($check) !== False) {
      return True;
    } else {
      return False;
    }
  }

  function check_pdf($filename) {
    // Check mime type using PHPs own built in functions (as client side mime type is vulnerable to exploitation)
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($filename);
    $allowed_file_types = ['application/pdf'];

    // Perform checks
    if (in_array($mime_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
      return True;
    } else {
      return False;
    }
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  // CHECK FILES TO ENSURE THEY MEET REQUIREMENTS
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['fileupload']['name']))) {
    foreach ($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
      if (!(check_image($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'][$key]) || check_pdf($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'][$key]))) {
        echo ("The files do not meet the uploaded file requirements");
        exit;
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo ("There were no files requested to be uploaded.");
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: `print_r()` Doesn't tell you the whole story. `name` could be an empty string, or null, or false, or any number of things that PHP doesn't print anything for. Use `var_dump()` instead, which tells you exactly what it is.

Comment: That still gives me a similar output that I can't really figure out much with: `array(1) { ["fileupload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) "Screen Shot 2020-12-23 at 2.09.56 PM.png" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }`

Comment: In comparison, this is the var_dump for an image that uploads fine. `array(1) { ["fileupload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Red.png" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(66) "/private/var/folders/z2/6ch56kzj67501zt4lg57r55m0000gn/T/phpNh69Oc" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(3974) } } }`

Comment: `["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) }` [Docs:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) " UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE : Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini." I didn't scroll over far enough to see this before. Check your settings, and also check `$_FILES` entries for errors.